# Another malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc issue with pthreads and mqueue

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, malloc, assertion

I read a lot of **malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc:** topiccs but I couldn't find any solution for my problem. My head gave up to work in this might, I am asking you. Here it is:

I have `sensors.h` `sensors.c` and `main.c` files. I want to exchange messages between two functions (threads) in different files (sensors.c and main.c) wiht message queues. gcc compiler compiles it wihtout any error as usual but when attempting to run it, I receive assertion error `malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion (old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins.....`

```
 file:sensor.h

 typedef struct vector {
      double x;
      double y;
      double z;
 } vector_t;

 typedef struct all_vectors {
      vector_t *gyro;
      vector_t *accel;
      vector_t *magnet;
 } vectors_t;



 file:main.c:

 #include "sensors.h"

 vectors_t *vectors; // global  
 pthread_t threads[3]; 
 int rc;

 int main()
 {
  ....
   vectors        = (vectors_t *)malloc(sizeof(vectors_t *));
   vectors->gyro   = (vector_t *)malloc(sizeof(vector_t *));
   vectors->accel  = (vector_t *)malloc(sizeof(vector_t *));
   vectors->magnet = (vector_t *)malloc(sizeof(vector_t *));
   ....
   mq_attribute.mq_msgsize = sizeof(vectors_t *);
   mq_attribute.mq_maxmsg = 10;
   mq_attribute.mq_curmsgs = 0;
   mq_attribute.mq_flags = 0;
   ....
   mqd1 = mq_open(mq_name1, O_RDWR | O_CREAT , 0777, &mq_attribute); // create mq

   rc = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, (void *) &readSensors, (void *) vectors);

   ...
  }


 void readSensors(void *data)
 {
      vectors_t *vecs = (vectors_t *)data;

      mqd_t mqd_send = mq_open(mq_name1, O_WRONLY);
      printf("readSensors mq_open mq_name1:  %s\n", strerror(errno));

      while(loop)
      {

           readGyro(vecs->gyro);
           readAccel(vecs->accel);
           readMagnet(vecs->magnet);

           mq_send(mqd_send, (char *) vecs, sizeof(vectors_t *), 1);
           printf("readSensors mq_send mq_name1:  %s\n", strerror(errno));
      }

      pthread_exit((void*) 0);
 }
```

When I run it with gdb, it gives that error while runing this line `rc = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, (void *) &readSensors, (void *) vectors);` 
Of course, I am using the return values of the `pthread_` and `mq_` functions, I didn't mention here in order to minimize the code. I am using Raspberry Pi and I think that good programm valgrind doesn't run on Raspberry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't mallocing enough space. All your `malloc()` calls should use `sizeof(type)` not `sizeof(type *)`.

You're expecting there to be to be enough room for the whole of `struct all_vectors` but only creating enough for a single pointer. You then write to it as if there was enough space, but it ends up writing beyond the end of your malloced memory.

The same problem exists for all your `struct vector` mallocs, however, you don't write to them in this example so there isn't any problem symptoms.